# Magento 2.1 less not updating on frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, less

Im using Magento 2.1 with ubuntu.

I am creating a custom theme that inherits from a third party theme.
The problem I am encountering is that I am overriding the .less files and making my changes, however the changes are not appearing when I refresh.

Am I possibly not overriding the correct files?

I have cleared the cache and also "Flush Static Files Cache".

What should I do to ensure my changes are not overridden by the parent? Use _extend.less?

Comment: Have you tried deleting contents of the pub/static and var/view_preprocessed directories?

Comment: Yeah, deleted the contents of those :/

Comment: Which files are you attempting to override?

Comment: You were correct, my browser was also caching. Using ctrl + shift + r and clearing these folders worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into this issue myself... doing the following fixed it:

Make sure you have added your theme into the `dev/tools/grunt/configs/theme.js`. It should look like this:

```
<your_theme>: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: '<Package>/<theme>',
    locale: 'xx_YY',
    files: [
        'css/source/_extend'
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
}
```

Make sure your Magento is in development mode, you can read more about modes [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html). Turn on client-side compilation (`STORES > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer > Frontend Development Workflow`).

Clean all the files in `pub/static/` and `var/view_processed` like so:

`grunt clean:<your_theme>`

Flush the cache:

`bin/magento cache:flush`

Run the following Grunt commands like stated in the [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html#client-side):

```
grunt exec:<your_theme>
grunt less:<your_theme>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had to make sure pub/static/ and var/view_processed were cleared out. Also, i had ensure my browser wasn't caching.
Clearing the static and view_processed folders, plus using ctrl + shift + r to refresh the pages on the browser.